# QString::replace doesnt replace

Tags: c++, qt, replace, c++17, qstring

### Problem

I am trying to convert a string to a C string. In doing so, I need to replace `"` with `\"`. I use the following code to do this:

```cpp
QString Converter::plain2C(const QString &in) {
    QString out;

    // Split input in each line
    QStringList list = in.split(QChar('\n'));
    for (int i = 0; list.length() > i; i++) { // Go throught each line of the input
        QString line = list[i]; // Thats the line

        line.replace(QChar('\\'), QLatin1String("\\\\")); // replace \ with \\
        line.replace(QChar('"'), QLatin1String("\\\"")); // replace " with \"

        // For printf()
        if(escapePercent)
            line.replace(QChar('%'), QLatin1String("%%"));

        // If option "Split output into multiple lines" is active add a " to the output
        if (multiLine)
            out.append(QChar('"'));

        // append the line to the output
        out.append(line);

        // append a "\n" to the output because we are at the end of a line
        if (list.length() -1 > i)
            out.append(QLatin1String("\\n"));

        // If option "Split output into multiple lines" is active add a " and \n to the output
        if (multiLine) {
            out.append(QChar('"'));
            out.append(QChar('\n'));
        }
    }

    if (!multiLine) {
        out.prepend(QChar('"'));
        out.append(QChar('"'));
    }

    return out;
}
```

However, `"` is still there without a `\` before.

### Information

- Qt Version 5.15.3
- C++17

### Edit

The application is used to enter a normal string copied from the Internet and get as a result a string that can be copied into a C/C++ program.

#### More code

```cpp
void Converter::run()
{
    if (_from != From::NotSupportet &&
            _to != To::toInvalid) {
        QString out;

        // More code obove and below
        else if (_from == From::Plain) {
            switch (_to) {
            case To::toCString:
                out = plain2C(_in);
                break;
            
        // Emits the ready string which is applied direct to a QPlainTextEdit
        emit htmlReady(out);
    }
}
```

### Edit 2

Added more comments to the code

Comment: `replace` returns a new instance I think, rather than modifying the current?

Comment: @TZHX [all overloads of `QString::replace`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html) are none const methods and return `QString &`. So you are wrong.

Comment: I think we need to see the code where you check whether your function has worked. I can't see the problem in the code you wrote, so maybe the problem is where you check the returned string.

Comment: I suspect just confusion by this part of logic: `if (multiLine)` - it adds `"` without \ prefix.

Comment: @Marek R: The input is split in each row and stored in a list, I then go through each row and if the "output to multiple rows" option is enabled it adds a `"` to the beginning and end of each row.

Comment: @TimGromeyer -- How did you determine that `"` is still in the string?  And why not output what is being done at each step?  And why all of this code if the issue is just `"`?  Wouldn't a simple 3 or 4 line function be sufficient to show the issue?

Comment: I accidentally hit enter, the comment wasn't ready yet. Sorry for that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie:
> How did you determine that " is still in the string?

I don't. Qt takes care of whether it is present or not, so I don't need to check it

Comment: @TimGromeyer -- So basically you've done zero debugging.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh, you meant debugging. I have done some debugging. Has brought me only more to despair. The last solution after debugging, google and testing is stackoverflow. Now I am here.

Comment: @TimGromeyer If such a fundamental part of Qt string handling was broken, you should have created a very simple program that attempts to replace the `"`, and temporarily forget about all of this other code you have now.  If that simple program removes `"`, then the issue is more than likely all of the logic you are adding to your larger program (like the `multiLine` and other things), causing the program to take a code path you are not expecting.  Very simple step-by-step debugging would or should have solved what is going on.

Comment: @TimGromeyer If the simple program indeed proves that Qt is broken, you have something to show the engineers over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now. The problem was the line above:

> ```cpp
> line.replace(QChar('\'), QLatin1String("\\\\")); // replace \ with \\
> ```

The problem was that the comment ended with 2 `\`. That somehow disabled the next line or something like that.

Anyway, this is the working code:

```cpp
QString Converter::plain2C(const QString &in) {
    QString out;

    // Split input in each line
    QStringList list = in.split(QChar('\n'));
    for (int i = 0; list.length() > i; i++) { // Go throught each line of the input
        QString line = list[i]; // Thats the line

        line.replace(QChar('\\'), QLatin1String("\\\\")); // replace "\" with "\\"
        line.replace(QChar('"'), QLatin1String("\\\"")); // replace " with \"

        // For printf()
        if(escapePercent)
            line.replace(QChar('%'), QLatin1String("%%"));

        // If option "Split output into multiple lines" is active add a " to the output
        if (multiLine)
            out.append(QChar('"'));

        // append the line to the output
        out.append(line);

        // append a "\n" to the output because we are at the end of a line
        if (list.length() -1 > i)
            out.append(QLatin1String("\\n"));

        // If option "Split output into multiple lines" is active add a " and \n to the output
        if (multiLine) {
            out.append(QChar('"'));
            out.append(QChar('\n'));
        }
    }

    if (!multiLine) {
        out.prepend(QChar('"'));
        out.append(QChar('"'));
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Wow I'm impressed you worked it out.

Comment: IDE should show something fishy happens, since next line should be displayed gray. Even SO indicates this issue :). Also when debugging line suddenly gets skipped.

Comment: Ok I've checked Xcode, VisualStudo, Visual Studio Code and Qt Creator and all are failing :| and do not make next line gray.

Comment: BTW enable warnings in compiler. All compilers are detecting this issue and filing a warning: https://godbolt.org/z/hs91j8Yvx

Comment: I had no warning with gcc 11.2. But Qt Creator 8 actually grayed out the line. I didn't think anything about it because sometimes the code highlighting doesn't work.